# How does an airline pilot log P1U/S time under EASA regulations?

Tags: easa-regulations, logging, airline-pilot, pic

I am looking for the exact way to log P1 Under Supervision (P1U/S) time for Commercial Airline Pilots (FOs).

I know as a fact that, as a Pilot Flying first officer, you can log up to 500 hours in P1U/S which are counted as PIC time towards unfreezing the ATPL (must be countersigned by the captain).

However, I am not sure if I need to also log the SIC time in the same entry of the logbook (same flight)? Where can I find the exact regulation about this?